# Envio de formulário para banco de dados com Mysql, Html e php

Tags: php

Estou tentando mandar para um banco mysql os dados gravados por um formulário. Tenho criado um BD 'db_provida' e uma tablela 'testemunho' com 4 colunas. Eu não consigo fazer esse código gravar o registro. Aqui os componentes:
**Tabela 'testemunho':**
 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código html**:

```
<form action="testemunho.php" method="post">
    Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/>
    <br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <br>
    Testemunho: <textarea name="testemunho" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

**E código php**:

```
<?php
    //verifica se existe conexão com bd; caso não tenta, cria uma nova
    $conexao = mysql_connect('localhost','giuseppe','joanin21') //porta, usuário, senha
    or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados"); //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão

    $select_db = mysql_select_db("db_provida"); //seleciona o banco de dados

    //Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
    $nome = $_POST['nome']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $testemunho = $_POST['testemunho'];

    $string_sql = "INSERT INTO testemunho (id,nome,email,testemunho) VALUES (null,'$nome','$email','$testemunho')"; //String com consulta SQL da inserção

    mysql_query($string_sql,$conexao); //Realiza a consulta

    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
        echo "<p>Testemunho Registrado</p>";
        echo '<a href="testimonianze.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
    } else {
        echo "Erro, não foi possível inserir no banco de dados";
    }

    mysql_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados 
?>
```

Comment: Qual o erro? [Recomendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql/4675#4675).

Comment: Oi Francisco! É que não encontro nada de gravado na tabela 'testemunho', nem ele apresenta qual erro está acontecendo. Como se o formulário não passasse pelas tags do testemunho.php.

Comment: editei a resposta com mais detalhes e também um exemplo do seu código rodando no meu servidor

Comment: Oi Leo!Muito obrigado por compartilhar os seus conhecimentos. Eu trabalho num centro de telecomunicações de uma universidade e, somente agora me dei conta que o ambiente da minha máquina (compartilhada com outros usuários) tem o mariaDB como gerenciador de banco de dados e o nginex como servidor web. Ainda estou controlando, mas acho que o problema da falta de comunicação com o DB deve ser uma questão do ambiente da localhost.

Comment: Ok Leo! De fato, deletei tudo o que tinha no www - onde até tinha um Joomla instalado - e, colocando este teu código, tudo voltou a funcionar certinho, também com a gravação das strings. Obrigado mano!

Comment: então não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu rodei seu script com PHP 5.4.43 e rodou direitinho!

Só ficou faltando um `if (isset($_POST...` para que não haja `insert` ao entrar na pagina, pois do jeito que está vai inserir campos nulos ao acessar a página. Depois preenchendo os campos vai inserir direitinho!

Seu caso deve ser o abaixo explicado.

As funções `mysql_connect`, `mysql_affected_rows` ficaram obsoletas no PHP 5.5.0 e as funções mysql_ * foram removidas no PHP7!  Saiba mais com [[[image]]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869)

**Aproveita a ocasião e atualize-se!**

Com [**MySQLi**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)  a conexão pode ser feita do seguinte modo:

```
//aqui é só um exemplo para não rodar o script abaixo sem necessidade
if ((isset($_POST['email']))&&(!empty($_POST['email']))){

   //porta, usuário, senha, nome data base
   //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão
   $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "giuseppe", "joanin21", "db_provida") or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados " . mysqli_error($conexao));

  //Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
  $nome = $_POST['nome']; 
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $testemunho = $_POST['testemunho'];

   $string_sql = "INSERT INTO testemunho (id,nome,email,testemunho) VALUES (null,'$nome','$email','$testemunho')";
   $insert_member_res = mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql);
   if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao)>0){ //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
       echo "<p>Testemunho Registrado</p>";
       echo '<a href="testimonianze.html">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
   } else {
       echo "Erro, não foi possível inserir no banco de dados";
   }
   mysqli_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados
}else{
    echo "Por favor, preencha os dados";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A query que você coloca na variável `$string_sql` está considerando as variáveis `$nome, $email e $testemunho` como string. O maneira certa de fazer isso, ou seja, pras variáveis não serem consideradas string, tem que ser feito assim:

```
$string_sql = "INSERT INTO testemunho (id,nome,email,testemunho) VALUES (null,'{$nome}','{$email}','{$testemunho}')"; //String com consulta SQL da inserção
```

Comment: Oi! Substitui a linha mas ainda não está gravando na tabela. Além disso, não está mostrando nem o erro de conexão previsto no php.

Comment: Coloca isso no começo do arquivo PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` . Roda o código de novo e vê se vai mostrar algum erro.

Comment: eu uso values ('$nome', sem problemas