# Problemas ao banco de dados erro 404

Tags: php

Senhores eu estou com problema quando mando dados ao banco de dados,por ser aprendizado e teste (primeira vez em que me conecto ao banco de dado e envio dados) irei deixar, servername,database,username,password.

na pasta ouvidoria, peguei um formulário em que vi [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231781/envio-de-formul%C3%A1rio-para-banco-de-dados-com-mysql-html-e-php) no Stackoverflow  criei o banco de dados igual ao dele pois é a mesma coisa que quero fazer (quero pega os comentários e reclamações sobre o local) então deixei igual ao dele mudando somente a ultima linha (testemunho, para comentario)

**ultima imagem do post é o erro que aprensenta depois de clicar em enviar** [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os arquivos estão tudo na mesma pasta (no /public_html) como mostra na imagem abaixo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
segue o a pagina ouvidoria.html que onde fica o preenchimento do cliente

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Titulo</title>
        <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/icone/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/icone/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="194x194" href="img/icone/favicon-194x194.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="img/icone/android-chrome-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/icone/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

        <style>
            body {
                font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
                line-height: 1.8;
                color:darkturquoise;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 24px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #303030;
                font-weight: 600;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size: 19px;
                line-height: 1.375em;
                color: #303030;
                font-weight: 400;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }  
            .jumbotron {
                background-color: #33ccff;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 1px px;
                font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
                margin-top: 2cm; 

            }
            .container-fluid {
                padding: 6px 50px;
                color: black;
            }
            .bg-grey {
                background-color: #f6f6f6;
            }
            .logo-small {
                color: RED;
                font-size: 50px;
            }
            .logo {
                color: #f4511e;
                font-size: 200px;
            }
            .thumbnail {
                padding: 0 0 15px 0;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 0;
            }
            .thumbnail img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
                background-image: none;
                color: #1176BC;
            }
            .carousel-indicators li {
                border-color: #1176BC;
            }
            .carousel-indicators li.active {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .item h4 {
                font-size: 19px;
                line-height: 1.375em;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-style: italic;
                margin: 70px 0;
            }
            .item span {
                font-style: normal;
            }
            .panel {
                border: 1px solid #33ccff; 
                border-radius:0 !important;
                transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
            }
            .panel:hover {
                box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
            }
            .panel-footer .btn:hover {
                border: 1px solid #1176BC;
                background-color: #fff !important;
                color: #1176BC;
            }
            .panel-heading {
                color: #fff !important;
                background-color: #33ccff !important;
                padding: 25px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
                border-top-left-radius: 0px;
                border-top-right-radius: 0px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
            }
            .panel-footer {
                background-color:important;
            }
            .panel-footer h3 {
                font-size: 32px;
            }
            .panel-footer h4 {
                color: #aaa;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .panel-footer .btn {
                margin: 15px 0;
                background-color: green;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .navbar {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                background-color: #009BCE;
                z-index: 9999;
                border: 0;
                font-size: 12px !important;
                line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
                letter-spacing: 4px;
                border-radius: 0;
                font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
            }
            .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
                color: #fff !important;
            }
            .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
                color: black !important;
                background-color: #fff !important;

            }
            .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
                border-color: transparent;
                color: #fff !important;

            }
            footer .glyphicon {
                font-size: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                color: #f4511e;
            }
            .slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
            .slide {
                animation-name: slide;
                -webkit-animation-name: slide;
                animation-duration: 1s;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            @keyframes slide {
                0% {
                    opacity: 0;
                    transform: translateY(70%);
                } 
                100% {
                    opacity: 1;
                    transform: translateY(0%);
                }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes slide {
                0% {
                    opacity: 0;
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
                } 
                100% {
                    opacity: 1;
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                .col-sm-4 {
                    text-align: center;
                    margin: 25px 0;
                }
                .btn-lg {
                    width: 100%;
                    margin-bottom: 35px;
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
                .logo {
                    font-size: 150px;
                }
            }
            img{
                width: 100%;
                align-items: center;
            }

        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Inicio</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.html#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#especialidades">Especialidades</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#covienios">Convênios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#pricing">Partiular</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contato</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#map">Localização</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ouvidoria.html">Ouvidoria</a></li>   
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row fluid">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <h1>Empresa</h1> 
                <p>Ha mais de 60 anos no ramo !</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="connection2.php" method="post">
            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/>
            <br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
            <br>
            reclamação: <textarea name="comentario" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea> <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Segue o que tem no arquivo connection2.php (onde tem senha e usuario e local)

```js
<?php
//verifica se existe conexão com bd; caso não tenta, cria uma nova
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (!empty($_POST['email']))) {

    //porta, usuário, senha, nome data base
    //caso não consiga conectar mostra a mensagem de erro mostrada na conexão
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id3774441_test123", "teste", "id3774441_test") or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados " . mysqli_error($conexao));

    //Abaixo atribuímos os valores provenientes do formulário pelo método POST
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentraio'];

    $string_sql = "INSERT INTO teste (id,nome,email,comentario) VALUES (null,'$nome','$email','$comentario')";
    $insert_member_res = mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0) { //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
        echo "<p>reclamacao Registrado</p>";
        echo '<a href="index.html#sobre">Voltar para formulário de cadastro</a>'; //Apenas um link para retornar para o formulário de cadastro
    } else {
        echo "Erro, não foi possível inserir no banco de dados";
    }
    mysqli_close($conexao); //fecha conexão com banco de dados
} else {
    echo "Por favor, preencha os dados";
}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: está sim :/ @Oliveira

Comment: Verifique se os parâmetros da conexão estão, https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.construct.php . Em ordem, host, username, passwd, db_name.

Comment: está em ordem :/

Answer (score 0):

Meu caro, para encontrar o erro, eu recomendo tratar por partes, até identificar o real problema.

- Escreva apenas um `echo "Hello word";` em seu arquivo connection2.php.
- Verificar se a URL do redirecionamento do formulario está correta.

Após esse simples 'Hello word' for exibido na tela, você pode verificar se o formulário está sendo enviado com um `var_dump($_POST)`. Caso o formulário seja enviado normalmente, faça toda sua tratativa do formulário e exiba sua mensagem.

Não fugindo do seu código, algo como:

```
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (!empty($_POST['email']))) {
   echo "Formulário enviado com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Por favor, preencha os dados";
}
```

Caso tenha tudo funcionado, valide sua conexão com o banco e execute a query sem depender das variáveis.

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id3774441_test123", "teste", "id3774441_test") or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados " . mysqli_error($conexao));

$string_sql = "INSERT INTO teste (id,nome,email,comentario) VALUES (null,'teste','teste','Testando insert')";
$insert_member_res = mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0) {
    echo "Inserido com sucesso".
} else {
    echo "Erro, não foi possível inserir no banco de dados";
}
```

Bem, acredito que validando passo a passo do que acontece na sua aplicação, será melhor para identificar e tratar seu erro.